# Google plus unable to load people

Tags: android, google-plus

I try to use google plus api in my Android aplication. [I follow sample code](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people)

I succesfully connected to google plus, and request load people, but personBuffer count is 0. But I have some people in my groups.

Please tell me any idea? Maybe I forget any addition scope? I add only Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN. in documentation it is enough.

My complete authtorization code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this).setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN, Scopes.PLUS_PROFILE)
                .setVisibleActivities("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity").build();

        // Progress bar to be displayed if the connection failure is not
        // resolved.
        mConnectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mConnectionProgressDialog.setMessage("Signing in...");

    }


@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR && responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mConnectionResult = null;
            mPlusClient.connect();
        }
    }
@Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        String accountName = mPlusClient.getAccountName();
//      mPlusClient.loadPerson(this, "104242357859551899867");
//
        mPlusClient.loadPeople(MainActivity.this, Person.Collection.VISIBLE);

        Toast.makeText(this, accountName + " is connected. try to load persons", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
@Override

public void onPeopleLoaded(ConnectionResult status, PersonBuffer personBuffer, String nextPageToken) {
    Log.i("", "persons loaded result = " + status.toString() + ", personsCount = " + personBuffer.getCount()
            + ", token = " + nextPageToken);
    if (status.isSuccess()) {
        Iterator<Person> itP = personBuffer.iterator();
        while (itP.hasNext()) {
            Person person = itP.next();
            Log.i("", person.getNickname());
        }
    }

}
```

My complete logcat:

```
    06-14 11:38:43.451: D/libEGL(779): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
06-14 11:38:43.451: D/libEGL(779): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
06-14 11:38:43.451: D/libEGL(779): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
06-14 11:38:43.451: I/Adreno200-EGL(779): <eglInitialize:269>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: Nondeterministic AU_full_mako_PARTNER-ANDROID/JB-MR1-DEV_CL2961380_release_AU (CL2961380)
06-14 11:38:43.451: I/Adreno200-EGL(779): Build Date: 12/10/12 Mon
06-14 11:38:43.451: I/Adreno200-EGL(779): Local Branch: 
06-14 11:38:43.451: I/Adreno200-EGL(779): Remote Branch: m/partner-android/jb-mr1-dev
06-14 11:38:43.451: I/Adreno200-EGL(779): Local Patches: NONE
06-14 11:38:43.451: I/Adreno200-EGL(779): Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
06-14 11:38:43.491: D/OpenGLRenderer(779): Enabling debug mode 0
06-14 11:38:44.993: I/(779): persons loaded result = ConnectionResult{statusCode=SUCCESS, resolution=null}, personsCount = 0, token = null
06-14 11:38:45.013: D/dalvikvm(779): GC_CONCURRENT freed 165K, 3% free 8898K/9092K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 27ms
```

Comment: make sure that your google plus account has all the details or try to login with other google plus account

Comment: I tried to log into another account, all the same

Comment: ok,paste your complete logcat

Comment: I'm add complete logcat to post

Comment: do you want to load person or people?

Comment: Could you please add your complete code used for authorization..

Comment: for dd619, I want to load people, from user groups who login

Comment: for Manikandan, I'm sorry. I edited post, now it contains complete auth code

Comment: you need to have different Scopes to load People information

Comment: what scopes do you mean?

Comment: i tried with different scopes, but without result..

Comment: today i try to share text info for posts. it works fine, but loading people don't work

Answer (score 0):

The solve is to initialize PlusClient like this:

```
mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this).build();
```

above code works fine.